# Replace absolute to relative path in asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, relative-path

I have a upload function in ASP.NET MVC 4.5.2 how upload picture to ~/Uploads/.

When I want to display image with following code:

```
<img src="@item.ImagePath" alt="Image" />
```

I obtain:

```
<img src="c:\users\yanni\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\Uploads/references/postfinance.PNG" alt="Image" />
```

My question is to know how i can replace c:\users ... by "~/Uploads/filename.ext".

Maybe it's important to specify: in my Database, i have the full link: c:\users\yanni\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\Uploads/references/postfinance.PNG

referenced by this ControllerCode:

```
references.ImagePath = HttpContext.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "Uploads/references/" + ImagePath.FileName;
ImagePath.SaveAs(references.ImagePath);
```

Thanks per advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution founded:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Compagny,Website,Logo")] References references, HttpPostedFileBase ImagePath)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(ImagePath.FileName);
                references.ImagePath = "/Uploads/References/" + fileName;
                ImagePath.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/References/" + fileName));

                db.References.Add(references);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(references);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out something like this:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Uploads/Image.png")" />
```

If you want image to be fetched according to the current request

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Uploads/" + FileName)" />
```

where file name is nothing but the name of the image or

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Uploads/" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(@item.ImagePath))" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I really don't get why you say you upload to "~/Uploads", but later you store ImagePath as "Uploads/**references**/...". Why do you append that dir? Do you move that file there?

In general: I'd better store image path in the database as relative, so you can anytime relocate the project.

```
var fileName = "~/Uploads/" + ImagePath.FileName;
references.ImagePath = fileName;
```

And if you ever need absolute path of the image on your server (which depends on where is your project located on server), you can get it in controller by

```
var realPath = Server.MapPath(fileName);
```

Thanks to this approach will this code:

```
 <img src="@item.ImagePath" alt="Image" />
```

render to:

```
 <img src="~/Uploads/postfinance.PNG" alt="Image" />
```

Which is probably what you want...

Comment: thanks for your answer.

With your code (the first), i obtain this error:

Additional information: The SaveAs method is configured to require an associated path to a root, and the path ~ / Uploads / postfinance.PNG 'is not associated with a root.